# What is the significance of showing "This text was adapted from Google’s tips for getting help." in Ask question section?

Tags: bug, status-completed, post-ban

I recently noticed a thing in my [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3118979/kiran-rs) account, when I'm trying to ask a question,

> You have reached your question limit

page will come. But on the right side I've seen

> **Linked**
>
> This text was adapted from Google’s [tips for getting help.](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/tips-for-getting-help-with-your-site.html)

I would like to know why it is showing in this area?

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Looks like we just re-used the page template from [/questions/ask/advice](/questions/ask/advice). Oops.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this a while back; was borrowing unnecessary bits from [the ask EULA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice).

[image]

Comment: Are you able to login to my account?

Comment: No, @KiranRS - why?